# Intercept traffic from exe to my Java server

Tags: java, networking

In Windows 10, I can easily intercept traffic of an application using Proxifier and route it to Charles proxy, so that I can inspect and edit the data.

```
 exe -> Proxifier (Socks proxy to localhost:8889) -> Charles (socks listen localhost:8889)
```

I now would like to replace Charles with my own Java server.

```
public void StartListener(int port) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8889), 0);
    server.createContext("/MyHandler", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();
}
```

While this works fine if I turn off Proxifier (or even if it's on) open Chrome and navigate to `localhost:8889/MyHandler` it does not when the exe tries to connect to `ExeWebsite.com:80/MyHandler`.

I tried settings up Proxifier either as Socks or Http proxy but nothing.

I also tried to edit the Java server like this, as per [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html?is-external=true):

```
HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("ExeWebsite.com", 80), 0);
```

The result I see in Proxifier log is:

> exe.exe *64 - ExeWebsite.com:80 error :
>   Could not connect through proxy 127.0.0.1:8882 - Proxy server cannot
>   establish a connection with the target, status code 400

Which tool should I use to quickly and painlessly redirect all the traffic to my local server?

Comment: You can set up your own DNS server with a tool like [dnschef](http://thesprawl.org/projects/dnschef/) and respond to DNS A requests for `exewebsite.com` with `127.0.0.1`. In that way you need not bother with "redirecting" the traffic.